# tapGesture change color

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am trying to make a `UIImageView` named `rDot` tappable with tapGesture. When the image view `rDot` is tapped I want a different `UIImageView` on a different viewController, named *wCircle* to turn red. The problem is the code runs, but when I tap `rDot` the other image `wCircle` doesn't turn red.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
    rDot.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    rDot.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
}    

func imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
 let wCircle = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named:"wCircle")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)) //error here
    wCircle.tintColor = UIColor.red
}
```

Comment: **You cannot change your question to something completely different after it has been answered.** That is unfair to the people who have written answers, and is not allowed on Stack Overflow. If you have a follow-up question, then you should ask a new question. You can include a link to the old one if you need to provide context. Since this question is a mess, with answers to all sorts of different "versions" of the question, I've closed it. Ask a new one if you are still having a problem.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of Swift code, EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION usually means you’ve hit a compiler trap, that is, an undefined instruction inserted into the code by the compiler because of a bug detected at runtime.  The most common cause of these are:

1. failure to unwrap an optional — This can be a forced unwrap (!) or an implicit unwrap (accessing an implicitly unwrapped optional that’s nil).
2. array out of bounds
3. a failed forced cast (as!), either because the value was a nil optional or because the value was of the wrong type.

Check if wCircle is not nil.
Check if the outlet is properly connected.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your image assets has an image exactly named "wCircle" case sensitive ,
again, in assets not in project bundle , i think UIImageView couldn't be initialized because an image with "wCircle" does not exist in assets

Answer (score 0):

The way you init your UITapGestureRecognizer is incorrect.
Try

```
UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
```

Replace `ViewController` with your controller's class name

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your object wCircle is present and initialize successfully

Answer (score 0):

What is "wCircle" ? UIImage has no property called `tintColor`, if you want change image's color change his container UIImageView's tintColor

Comment: Both images are UIImageViews